# Nested template class inside another template class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a templated binary search tree with a templated node definition inside the templated class, something like this:

```
template <class T>
class BST {
    template <class U>
    class BSTNode {
        BSTNode<U>* _left;

    public:
        BSTNode<U>* GetLeft();
    };
};

template <class T>
template <class U>
BST<T>::BSTNode<U>* BST<T>::BSTNode<U>::GetLeft() {
    return _left;
}
```

I want to define the method outside the class.
When I try to compile this, I get a bunch of errors. What am I doing wrong here? Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: `typename BST<T>::template BSTNode<U>* BST<T>::BSTNode<U>::GetLeft()`

Comment: Also, you *must* implement templated methods in the header in which they are defined (not sure exactly what you meant by 'outside the class'), they cannot go into a separate .cpp file.

Comment: @0x499602D2, You're the man! It works!@aruisdante, when I work with templates, I always put them in the same file.